# redirect from /subfolder/index.html to /subfolder/ using htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I know this question has been asked a lot of times before, but I still can't make it work properly and can't find a solution that would fit my configuration.

I have a website that consists of different language sections.
SEO audit says you have duplicate pages:

- `https://www.mywebsite.com/en/`
- `https://www.mywebsite.com/en/index.html`

I assume I have to either 301 redirect:

1. from /en/index.html to /en/ or
2. from /en/ to /en/index.html

Question 1: Which option would be the best in terms of SEO?

In mywebsite.com/en/ folder I have .htaccess file with the following code:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(|.+/)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This doesn't work.
Question 2: What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can use this `RewriteRule ^(.+?)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: this seems to fail as well

Comment: Do you have more than one .htaccess? Are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" exactly? Does anything happen? Do you get an error? (If you are asking about SEO then that is strictly off-topic on StackOverflow and should be asked on Webmasters instead... https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I guess it redirects to the root mybebsite.com/index.php that in turn, based on the saved language cookie, redirects to the corresponding language section like mywebsite.com/it/ (provided "it" was the last lang cookie set in the browser).

I'm testing htaccess in "fr" folder and input in the browser mywebsite.com/fr/index.html and get redirect to mywebsite.com/it/ instead of mywebsite.com/fr/

Comment: @George That would seem to be an issue with your server-side code, not `.htaccess`? The directive you posted in the question would redirect `/en/index.html` to `/en/` (as expected). However, there is an error with the preceding non-www to www canonical redirect - `/en` should not be present in the _susbstitution_ string - that could result in a malformed redirect (although unrelated to your current problem).

Comment: @AmitVerma That directive would match too much. `^(.+?)index.html$` should be more like `^(.+/)index\.html$` to ensure that only `.../index.html` is matched, rather than `/anythingindex.html`. (Or just use the directive already posted in the question which would also handle requests for the document root, although that's not strictly part of the stated requirements.)